# Java Draw Three Shapes Based on Mouse Clicks?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, awt, mouseevent

I'm new to drawing in Java and have been having some trouble working with the mouse listener event. What I am trying to do is draw a point on click, then draw a line that extends from that point on click, and finally the last point on click connects to make a triangle. As of now I am just working on getting the point and line to work. The way I have it now is close I think; a circle is drawn in the top corner instead of where the user clicks but on click a line is drawn from where the circle is. Tried using a boolean to decide when something should be drawn but have been unsuccessful..Thanks for any help.

**Main Class**

```
package TriangleDraw;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class TriangleDrawMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //create a frame or window

       JFrame frame = new JFrame();
       //set window size
       frame.setSize(500, 500);
       //set the title
       frame.setTitle("Triangle Draw");
       frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

       //add panel to frame and make it visible
       MouseComponent component = new MouseComponent();
       frame.add(component);
       frame.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

**Drawing Class**

```
package TriangleDraw;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;

public class MouseComponent extends JPanel implements MouseListener{
        boolean drawPoint = true;
        boolean drawLine = false;
        boolean drawTriangle = false;

    public MouseComponent(){
        super();
        pointX = 0;
        pointY = 0;   
        oldX = 0;
        oldY = 0;
        addMouseListener(this);
    }

    int pointX, pointY, oldX,oldY;

        @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if(drawPoint == true){
        g.drawOval(pointX,pointY,10,10);
        drawPoint = false;
        drawLine = true;
        oldX = pointX;
        oldY = pointY;
        }
        if(drawLine == true){
            g.drawLine(pointX, pointY, oldX, oldY);
        }


    }

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent mouse){

        pointX = mouse.getX();
        pointY = mouse.getY();

        repaint();
    }
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent mouse){ }   
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent mouse){ }
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent mouse){ }
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent mouse){ }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start drawPoint as `false`. And the change the names of your variables to save points.

Then you'll want something like this in your click:

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent mouse){
    if(!drawPoint)
    {
        pointX = mouse.getX();
        pointY = mouse.getY();
        drawPoint = true;
    }    
    else if(!drawLine)
    {
        lineX = mouse.getX();
        lineY = mouse.getY();
        drawLine = true;
    }
    repaint();
}
```

And then your paint is simple:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if(drawLine){
            g.drawLine(pointX, pointY, lineX, lineY);
        }
        else if(drawPoint){
            g.drawOval(pointX-5,pointY-5,10,10);
        }
}
```

It's actually important that in your paint loop, you check drawLine first, and in your mouseClicked you check drawPoint first.

Once you've grasped what's happening here, you can attempt the drawTriangle yourself!

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't change state in paintComponent, you don't know when that will be called (where you assign oldX and oldY). I suggest creating two Point objects, and switch between the two point objects in every other mouseClicked event.

If paintComponent is called more than once between mouseClicked, you'll end up having oldX and OldY equal to pointX and pointY.